# Tradingview Alert

Tags: alert, pine-script

I don't know how I can make alerts when the dots appear in the indicator.
Has anybody enough knowledge to do this?

Here's the [link](https://de.tradingview.com/v/Lmqh0eEr/) with the code.

```
study("Semafor", overlay=true)

zigzag(Depth, Deviation, Color) =>
    var lw = 1, var hg = 1
    lw := lw + 1, hg := hg + 1
    p_lw = -lowestbars(Depth), p_hg = -highestbars(Depth)
    lowing = lw == p_lw or low - low[p_lw] > Deviation*syminfo.mintick
    highing = hg == p_hg or high[p_hg] - high > Deviation*syminfo.mintick
    lh = barssince(not highing), ll = barssince(not lowing)
    down = lh > ll, lower = low[lw] > low[p_lw], higher = high[hg] < high[p_hg]
    if lw != p_lw and (not down[1] or lower)
        lw := p_lw < hg ? p_lw : 0
    if hg != p_hg and (down[1] or higher)
        hg := p_hg < lw ? p_hg : 0
    x1 = down ? lw : hg
    y1 = down ? low[lw] : high[hg]
    lb = down ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down
    label point = label.new(bar_index-x1, y1, color=Color, style=label.style_circle, size=size.tiny)
    if down == down[1]
        label.delete(point[1])

if input(true, "Small")
    zigzag(input(7, "Depth"), input(3, "Deviation"), input(color.lime, "Color"))
    
if input(true, "Medium")
    zigzag(input(14, "Depth"), input(6, "Deviation"), input(color.orange, "Color"))
    
if input(true, "Large")
    zigzag(input(72, "Depth"), input(24, "Deviation"), input(color.red, "Color"))
```

Comment: That code is redrawing labels all the time. Labels are plotted in the past, and can appear and at some point be erased n bars later. It's a nice display, but not designed to provide non-repainting alert-triggering conditions.