# Alert message include label text

Tags: label, pine-script

I'm writing a webhook implementation and would like to know if it is possible to include label information to the webhook alert message body.

So far, I've found that you can only include plot information. I've also looked for variables which provide all label objects within pinescript but couldn't find.

Comment: First, I would advice that you include some of the code you have tried into your question, else it will be flagged and removed.

Comment: Have you used the search function for your answer? I think the answer might already be out there. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825212/pinescript-use-text-variable-in-alerts/65832498#65832498
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865427/how-to-create-an-alert-in-pine-script-depending-on-the-result-of-dynamic-label